# Первый проект на django, models не появляются в БД

Tags: python, django

Я по курсу пишу первый проект на джанго, сделала два класса Pet и Vaccine, и добавила им атрибуты. Но в базе данных ничего не появляется. А когда пишу makemigrations или migrate - no changes detected, no migrations to apply. Думаю может проблема в том, что когда я только создала проект, сделала migrate

Как сделать так, чтобы то что я пишу, появлялось в базе данных?

Comment: Эм... А ты базу как смотрел? Через админку? А ты регал модели?

Comment: Базы открыла через sqlpro. А что значит регать модели и как смотреть через админку?

Comment: Не забыла свои модели унаследовать от `django.db.models.Model`?

Comment: Нет, не забыла.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько причин этой проблемы:

1. Папка `migrations` в папке приложения. Если ее нет - нужно создать и поместить туда пустой файл `__init__.py`.
2. Приложение отсутствует в `INSTALLED_APPS` -> `settings.py`.
3. Модели могут быть абстрактными(в таком случае миграции не будут создаваться), в `class Meta` **НЕ** должно быть `abstract = True`.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в том что вы сделали миграции как создали проект. При малейшем изменении в моделях должны перезаписываться миграции.
Что бы посмотреть модели в админке django. Скорее всего проблема в том что вы не указали(не зарегистрировали) в файле `admin` ваши модели. А именно :

```
admin.site.register(Pet)
admin.site.register(Vaccine)
```

А вообще желательно показать свой код задавая вопрос.

Ответ будет изменён после редактирования вопроса...